# Definition of a set of aggregates?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I'm struggling with how/if to define "a set of aggregates". Aggregates are supposed to be stand alone and isolated but it's easy to think of a bigger set of aggregates that belong together. But is this a trap?

Using this "set of aggregates" it would be possible to for instance enumerate and index aggregates on a unique property within the set and have other domain rules that could be validated across all aggregates in the set. It's tempting but also feels a bit wrong.

Another approach would be to avoid this thinking completely and not allow/define a set of aggregates and not allow enumerating aggregates but only load/save on aggregate-id. Using this option if would be necessary to reference aggregates from other aggregates and by doing this build up an interconnected graph of aggregates.

The approaches are similar to having aggregates in a folder on disk or having an "internet" of aggregates where the references between them are defining the bigger set of aggregates. In any case I'm really stuck on this problem. I have never read anywhere about this and I guess nobody really cares that much? I'm not sure I explain this very good but my question is if there are any definitions of the "set of aggregates" or if we should think of aggregates as totally isolated/on its own and with only a unique aggregate-id (UUID)?

The set of aggregates could for instance be the database being used under the surface. But what I'm wondering is if this database as in the information about what aggregates it contains has any definition in DDD or if we should think about a set of aggregates as an interconnected graph where only traversal of this graph can be used to enumerate all "associated" aggregates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Aggregates are connected**

In any application with sufficient complexity, Aggregates end up referencing one-another. And it is perfectly reasonable to use their unique identifiers as reference IDs to refer to each other.

But take care to load and persist aggregates outside the domain layer, typically in repositories. If you want to traverse links across aggregates and load them into memory, you will be doing that upfront before handing over control to the domain layer for the actual processing.

Traversing the graph to get all related aggregates is correct, but this rarely spans across too many aggregate boundaries. You rarely find a single change or rule to be applied throughout the application. If you do have such a transaction, it is probably a sign of the domain design needing improvement, simply because you are spreading one responsibility/change amongst many aggregates.

The connectivity is so usual that you should watch out for aggregates that have no linkages with the rest of the system. They are either standalone libraries, or they probably belong to a different bounded context.

**Aggregates can morph into different forms**

They are aggregates because they form a clear invariant boundary, with their primary responsibility being to enforce invariants across state changes for all the entities within themselves. But they can morph into different kinds of DDD objects based on the requirement.

A good example is of a single Currency note. In most applications, they are value objects. But for the federal bank, they are aggregates with clear cut invariant rules. They are aggregates when they are created and referenced, but in a transaction that ships printed notes to banks, they may become value objects.

So you may have to evaluate whether you are talking about a domain entity in its aggregate form, or as a value object when you consider each linkage.

**Aggregates are invariant boundaries**

It is wrong to validate domain rules across aggregates.

Your aggregate boundary is an invariant boundary, meaning all the domain rules within it should be satisfied at all time. By that logic, you are going to incorrectly build up a structure that will need to ensure that all domain rules across aggregates are valid at all time. Doing so will impose considerable performance burden, not to mention the complexity in business logic.

But this is not to say that there may be domain rules that span across aggregates. The correct way to accomplish this would be using eventual consistency and an Event-driven approach.

The primary changing aggregate would validate and persist the data, and bubble up an event containing the state change. Other aggregates would then act on the event and bring themselves up-to-date. If an aggregate's domain rules break because of the change, there is usually a supplementary mechanism that allows correction of the problem (a preferred mechanism) or a rollback of the first state change (happens very rarely).

Comment: Eventual consistency with domain events and compensations is probably the way to go but its also very tempting to use simpler locks and indexes etc which would be possible if having access to the list of aggregates within the database (or the more generic set). Is it ok to list aggregates from the repository? Or should aggregates (agg-ids) only be possible to discover through references in other aggregates? I'm thinking that each database/set could have one root-aggregate where all other aggregates can be found by navigating references. Or introduce enumeration in repositories.

Comment: I would suggest discovery through references as the way to go. But when it comes to loading aggregates, the thing to worry about is this: Is there a possibility that the root aggregate would load your entire database into memory? Would your application survive if that happens? You should imagine the domain layer dealing with objects as if they are available in memory all the time. So if the domain layer needs to traverse the linkage, it would require the dataset in memory.

Comment: I also think while this appears tempting, it is an extremely time-consuming process to traverse linkages like this, not to mention the problems of complexity and recursion. Is there a real use case you are thinking about or is this just theoretical exploration?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can find a common denominator the agg sets have in common and use that to work with?

A simplified example; there is a set of Books and a set of Users that have nothing in common except you want to know whenever they were first registered? What might be an option is to have an interface FirstRegistration and then you can choose to either expand Books/Users or create a specific entity instead.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm struggling with how/if to define "a set of aggregates". Aggregates
>   are supposed to be stand alone and isolated but it's easy to think of
>   a bigger set of aggregates that belong together. But is this a trap?

I think you're struggling because indeed the idea of a set of aggregates (instances) is very generic, and the uses of such things are contextual and domain-specific.  People don't talk specifically about it because *of course* you may have behaviors that operate on a collection of multiple aggregates, but that doesn't give such collections any particular common properties or requirements that would allow you, from a general DDD perspective, to characterize such collections more specifically than "a set of aggregates", "a list of distinct aggregates", or similar.

> Using this "set of aggregates" it would be possible to for instance
>   enumerate and index aggregates on a unique property within the set and
>   have other domain rules that could be validated across all aggregates
>   in the set. It's tempting but also feels a bit wrong.

Tempting why?  You've couched the question in very abstract terms, so it's pretty much impossible to contradict you about the "it would be possible", but just because something may be possible doesn't mean it would be *useful*.  In practice, I think you'll find that rules or behaviors that operate on collections of aggregates most naturally belong not to collections of aggregates in an abstract sense, but rather to other aggregate types in your domain model, to domain repositories, or to domain services.

It is entirely plausible that your domain model might want to handle particular sets of aggregates characterized by some rule.  For example, if you're an airline, then one of the aggregates in your domain model might a single seat on a flight, since that's the unit you sell.  It makes sense in that case that there would be operations on all the seats on a particular flight, for example, but whatever rules and behaviors you might have about that are specifically about that kind of aggregate, selected in that particular way.

> Another approach would be to avoid this thinking completely and not
>   allow/define a set of aggregates and not allow enumerating aggregates
>   but only load/save on aggregate-id.

It's surely counterproductive to *forbid* working with sets of aggregates.  Just don't attribute more significance to it than is warranted.  There is nothing particularly special about sets of aggregates in general.

> Using this option if would be
>   necessary to reference aggregates from other aggregates and by doing
>   this build up an interconnected graph of aggregates.

I don't follow that.  One certainly must be able to retrieve and store individual aggregates from persistence, as that's more or less the defining property of aggregates -- they are the unit of persistence.  But that doesn't mean that you must reject the ability to work with collections of aggregates.  However, sets of aggregates do not have *identity* in the same way that individual aggregates do, so yes, relationships between aggregates need to be modeled in terms of individual aggregates.  Nevertheless, that does not inherently preclude 1:m or n:m relationships among aggregates.

> I'm really stuck on this problem. I have never read anywhere about this and I guess nobody really cares that much?

You'll find all sorts of uses of various sets of aggregates in applications built and maintained based on DDD ideas, but there's not much to talk about at the level of abstraction of your question, and what there is is already summed up in the words "set" and "aggregate".

> The set of aggregates could for instance be the database being used
>   under the surface. But what I'm wondering is if this database as in
>   the information about what aggregates it contains has any definition
>   in DDD

Not to my knowledge.  I suspect most DDD practitioners would just call it "the data", or something similar.

> or if we should think about a set of aggregates as an
>   interconnected graph where only traversal of this graph can be used to
>   enumerate all "associated" aggregates.

I'm still not seeing why you set that up as a thing.  Sure, depending on the domain model, you might be able to traverse all or substantial chunks of the data by traversing associations between aggregates, and that might be appropriate for some purposes, but DDD doesn't have to give a special name or special rules for sets of aggregates for you to work with them.

Like any useful methodology, DDD exists to solve problems.  Its bread & butter is complex applications with complex data and evolving requirements.  It is not to be interpreted as a straight jacket preventing designers and developers from (thoughtfully) writing designs and code that incorporate aspects of other design approaches, much less designs and code that provide for the application's idiosyncratic needs.